# Why does collecting this Flow not terminate?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

As part of practicing coroutines and flow, I tried an implementation of RxJava's [amb](https://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/amb.html)/race operator where I don't allow myself to use channels directly.  Or, to put it differently, I use `shareIn` (SharedFlow).

It runs fine except that flow collection suspends indefinitely, even though the jobs used to collect the losing flows are completed and the winning flow has emitted all its items.

Why?

I spent a couple days trying to figure out what might be going on, without success.
Here's a gist of my work, including the code I'm using to test it, and the output generated.

You'll see from the output that the flow correctly emits the exception thrown by the first flow, and cancels the third flow because it emits last (so it loses the race), and all the items in the winning flow are emitted.

This is a learning exercise, so I'm interested in the shortest path to getting this implementation to work.  I'm not looking for a completely different implementation that works.

Also happy to create a project on Github with dependencies if anyone's interested in running the code directly.  Let me know.

(I use Arrow's [Either](https://arrow-kt.io/docs/apidocs/arrow-core/arrow.core/-either/) data-type which is basically a sealed class that represents the result of an operation.  Either has two sub-types, known as `Left` and `Right` where `Left` holds an error if there's one, and `Right` holds the happy path result of the operation.)

Thank you!

PS

Since the code seems to be difficult to grok, I'll summarize what it does.

1. Within a `flow` builder
2. Get a reference to the flow's job.  This will be our parent job.
3. Combine all the flows provided to the operator in a single list.
4. Map each emission of each flow to an Either.Right
5. Catch each exception of each flow and emit it as an Either.Left
6. Share each resulting flow in a CoroutineScope whose job's parent is the job in step 2.  Each flow gets its own job.
7. Transform the list of flows into a flow that emits the emissions of each of the flows i.e. flat-map the constituent flows.  Do this with concurrency set to the number of flows in the list, so that the constituent flows will be collected in parallel.
8. Collect the merged flow.  Emissions will be the Left-s or Right-s produced in steps 4, 5.
9. When collecting, emit Lefts and Rights to the outer flow of step 1.
10. If a Left is collected, cancel the job (created in step 6) of the flow that emitted the Left, so that the flow stops emitting.
11. If a Right is collected, cancel the jobs of any flows other than the flow that emitted the Right. Only cancel those flows that haven't already been cancelled.

```kotlin
@OptIn(FlowPreview::class)
fun <A> Flow<A>.ambUsingJobsToCancelRacersAndEmittingFailures(
    vararg others: Flow<A>
): Flow<Either<Throwable, A>> = flow {
    val parentJob = currentCoroutineContext()[Job]!!
    (listOf(this@ambUsingJobsToCancelRacersAndEmittingFailures) + others).foldIndexed(
        Pair(emptyList<Job>(), emptyList<Flow<Pair<Int, Either<Throwable, A>>>>())
    ) { index, acc, curr ->
        val job = Job(parentJob)
        val flow = curr.map { Pair(index, it.right() as Either<Throwable, A>) }
            .catch { emit(Pair(index, it.left() as Either<Throwable, A>)) }
            .onCompletion { println("completion $index $it") }
            .shareIn(CoroutineScope(job), SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed())
        Pair(acc.first + job, acc.second + flow)
    }.let { (jobs, flows) ->
        var winnerIndex: Int? = null
        flows.asFlow()
            .flatMapMerge(concurrency = flows.size) { it }
            .collect { (index, item) ->
                if (winnerIndex == null) {
                    item.fold(ifLeft = {
                        println("cancelling $index")
                        jobs[index].cancelAndJoin()
                    }, ifRight = {
                        winnerIndex = index
                        println("winnerIndex $winnerIndex")
                        jobs.forEachIndexed { i, job ->
                            if (!job.isCancelled && i != winnerIndex) {
                                println("cancelling $i")
                                job.cancelAndJoin()
                            }
                        }
                    })
                }
                emit(item)
                jobs.forEachIndexed { i, job ->
                    println("job cancelled $i ${job.isCancelled}")
                    println("job completed $i ${job.isCompleted}")
                }
            }
        println("done!")
    }
}

val e1 = Exception("Bang!")
val f1 = flow<Int> { throw e1 }.onStart { delay(50) }
val f2 = flowOf(1, 2, 3).onStart { delay(100) }
val f3 = flowOf(10, 20, 30).onStart { delay(150) }
val f4 = f1.ambUsingJobsToCancelRacersAndEmittingFailures(f2, f3)
f4.collect { // Emits expected items, then suspends indefinitely.
    println(it)
}
```

Output

```
completion 0 null
cancelling 0
Either.Left(java.lang.Exception: Bang!)
job cancelled 0 true
job completed 0 true
job cancelled 1 false
job completed 1 false
job cancelled 2 false
job completed 2 false
completion 1 null
winnerIndex 1
cancelling 2
completion 2 kotlinx.coroutines.JobCancellationException: Job was cancelled; job=JobImpl{Cancelling}@97269b4
Either.Right(1)
job cancelled 0 true
job completed 0 true
job cancelled 1 false
job completed 1 false
job cancelled 2 true
job completed 2 true
Either.Right(2)
job cancelled 0 true
job completed 0 true
job cancelled 1 false
job completed 1 false
job cancelled 2 true
job completed 2 true
Either.Right(3)
job cancelled 0 true
job completed 0 true
job cancelled 1 false
job completed 1 false
job cancelled 2 true
job completed 2 true
```

Comment: SharedFlows never complete, in general; it's in bold in their documentation.

Comment: @LouisWasserman Okay, so I should rephrase - `collect` suspends indefinitely, even after the jobs of two of the jobs have completed and the winning flow has emitted all its items.  Whereas I would have expected `collect` to continue.   Thanks!  (Updated question)

Comment: Why do you mention SharedFlow in your question? I don't see it in your code. The function is very complicated and hard to follow. Is the desired behavior that it emits all exceptions from the three sources until one of the sources emits a value, and then it only emits values from that flow while cancelling the others? I don't know the term amb.

Comment: @Tenfour04 Sorry for the difficulty and ambiguity.  I mention `SharedFlow`, but I'm not actually using it directly - I'm using the operator `Flow.shareIn`.  "Is the desired behavior that it emits all exceptions from the three sources until one of the sources emits a value, and then it only emits values from that flow while cancelling the others?"  - Yes, that's exactly it.  `amb` is an operator in RxJava, and is synonymous with `race`.  It's short for "ambiguous".  https://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/amb.html

Comment: Whether you explicitly call the MutableSharedFlow constructor or you wrap a flow using `shareIn`, you still end up with a SharedFlow, and by definition a SharedFlow suspends indefinitely when you collect it, regardless of whether any flows that it wraps are done.

Comment: @Tenfour04 Ah, so that may be the source of the indefinite suspension!  Do you have a suggestion for how to terminate this suspension?

Comment: Don't use SharedFlow if you want it to return. It is completely unavoidable with SharedFlow. Or make the `collect` call the last function call of your coroutine so it won't matter. When the scope it's running on is cancelled, it will terminate. Or emit some marker in your source flow that indicates the last item, and then follow up `shareIn` with `takeWhile`.

Comment: @Tenfour04 "...emit some marker in your source flow that indicates the last item" - that's a great idea.

Comment: That idea is right from the `shareIn` docs.

Comment: @Tenfour04 "When the scope it's running on is cancelled, it will terminate."  I tried something like this by cancelling what I refer to as the "parent job", which is the job of the outermost flow builder.  But it didn't help.  Shouldn't that have the same effect as cancelling the scope in which the `SharedFlow` is running?

Comment: Outermost, but still wrapped by `shareIn`? Doesn’t matter what you do to anything upstream of a SharedFlow. It will not terminate upon collection. It will terminate if the scope that shared in with is cancelled or if you used `whileSubscribed` and the collectors are all cancelled.

Comment: No, the outermost flow isn't upstream of the SharedFlow.  It's the flow that used to emit what's collected from the SharedFlow.  It "wraps around" the SharedFlow.

Comment: That should cancel the coroutine that's collecting, but the SharedFlow will still collect from its upstream flow silently if you didn't use SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243728/discussion-between-julian-a-and-tenfour04).